Combinatorics question about splitting groups of people

Five people are in a group, including Kai and Wen. To practice social
distancing, they first take the step of splitting the group into two
disjoint subgroups. Then, they undergo a series of additional steps,
during each of which they divide every remaining subgroup that has
more than 1 person into two further subgroups. The steps end when
every person is alone. Due to a long-standing grudge, Kai and Wen
cannot be together in the same subgroup after the first division.
Considering that the order of divisions matters and all remaining
subgroups are divided simultaneously at each step, how many possible
division pathways exist? A division pathway is considered the full
process starting from 1 group of 5 and ending at 5 groups of 1.

I get 48 (from 15 + 15 + 9 + 9) for this but I just want to make sure I am correct. So the group can be split into 1 and 4 or 3 and 2. There are 3 ways to split it into 2 and 3 and 1 way to split it into 1 and 4. From there, I think for the 3 + 2 case there are 9 ways to further divide them and for the 1 + 4 case there are 15 ways to further divide them, if my calculations are correct (using bruteforce). I would appreciate a second opinion.

How did you get 42? 3 x 6 + 15 = 33.

In any case you are under counting there are 2 ways to split into 1 and 4 depending on whether kai or wen is the 1.

Not sure the rules are clear.  Can they be together in the first split or not?  Suppose the people are $K,W, a,b,c$.  Is it possible for the first split to be $KW$ vs $abc$?

@RishiSonthalia Yes, I made a mistake. For the cases 1 +4 and 4+1 I think there are 15 pathways,

@lulu Kai and Wen cannot be together in the same subgroup after the first division.

As I say, the rules aren't clear so simply repeating them won't help.  I gave a concrete example of a possible first division.  Is it allowed by the rules?

@lulu No, because K and W would be together in that scenario. Sorry for the ambiguous wording

Ok, so the first division must separate them, meaning it must have the form $KS_1$ and $WS_2$ where $S_1\cup S_2={a,b,c}$ and of course $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$.  There are $8$ possible cases for $S_1$, though a lot of them can be handled by symmetry.  Anyway, I'd approach it that way.

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

I agree that it is $48$. The cases are relatively straightforward.
(Case 1: First split is $1 + 4$) The singleton must be either $K$ or $W$, so there are two choices there. In the next division of the $4$-group, we could either have $1 + 3$ or $2 + 2$.
(Case 1a: Second split is $1 + 3$) There are $4$ choices for who ends up in the second singleton. Following this, the third split is forced to be $1 + 2$ (and there are $3$ ways to choose who ends up in the third singleton). So, this case has $12$ ways.
(Case 1b: Second split is $2 + 2$) In this case, we pick who goes with either $K$ or $W$ (whoever wasn't singled out in the first round) - so there are $3$ ways here.
So, case $1$ has $2 (12 + 3) = 30$ total ways.
(Case 2: First split is $2 + 3$) In this case, there are $2$ choices for whether $K$ or $W$ ends up in the $2$-group, and $3$ choices for who joins in that group. In the second split, the $2$-group is split without any choices. For the larger $3$-group, the second split has to become $1 + 2$, and there are $3$ choices for who gets singled out. The third split does not come with any choices.
So, case $2$ has $(2) (3) (3) = 18$ total ways.
There are $30 + 18 = \boxed{48}$ ways total.

I think there are 54 division pathways. I believe your mistake is in counting the number of ways to split into 1 + 4.
Here's my breakdown:
Ignoring Kai and Wen's personal problems, groups of size 1 and 2 each yield a single division pathway. Groups of size 3 can be split 3 different ways (by choosing who is alone after the first division).
Groups of 4 can be split into 3+1 or 2+2.
You can choose 3+1 in 4 different ways (by choosing who goes into the 1-group), and each way yields 3 pathways for a total of 12 pathways.
You can choose 2+2 in 4C2=6 ways. Each of these groupings yields a single division pathway so 2+2 divisions yield a total of 6 pathways. Thus a group of 4 yields 18 pathways
Now for the real problem:
Let's call {Wen, Kai} the mean set, M, and everybody else is in the nice set, N.
We can either partition 5 into 2+3 or 1+4.
2+3 is uniquely determined by the makeup of the 2-group, which must contain exactly one meanie (2 choose 1 = 2) and one nice guy (3 choose 1 = 3) for a total of 6 choices. Each of these initial divisions yields 3 pathways (1 * 3 from independent choices of pathways for the 2 group and 3 group) for a total of 18 pathways.
1+4 is determined by which meanie goes into the singleton (2 choose 1 = 2). Each initial division yields 18 pathways, for a total of 36 pathways.
18 pathways for 2+3, 36 pathways for 1 + 4. That's 54 pathways in all.
